# JavaScript is not working in the html when the html is executed from a link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have two simple html files which has a link in body and a log in JavaScript. In A.html, it is a link to jump to B.html and a `console.log("a 123");` in JavaScript. However, the "a 123" message will only be showed when refresh the browser but not be executed from a link. For example, if i click the link `Go to a` in b.html, the message "a 123"  will not be showed.

Any idea?

-----A.html-------

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="a">

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href='b.html'>Go to b</a>
  </div>

</div> 


<script>
console.log("a 123");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

-----B.html-------

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="b">

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href='a.html'>Go to a</a>
  </div>


</div> 


<script>
console.log("b 123");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing `<link><link><script><script>` these links and it will print in console. 
there is something with Jquery.

Comment: ¿Do you really need jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js in your sample?. Remove it and  the page will work as expected

Comment: Interesting... It should work I think.

Comment: @pedrofb   Lots of code is omitted in my sample, some UI elements are created in JavaScript. The reason about why i am using jquery.mobile that i want to learn more programming language.

Comment: Ok, your problem seems simple, but the solution is not. Jquerymobile is a framework and has its own characteristics to learn and work with

Answer (score 2):

Bit of searching and I found the answer! Apparently it's a 'feature' of Jquery Mobile. It's using an Ajax navigation system. So it stays singlepage.

From the [docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation/):

> jQuery Mobile includes a navigation system to load pages into the DOM via Ajax, enhance the new content, then display pages with a rich set of animated transitions. The navigation system uses progressive enhancement to automatically 'hijack' standard links and form submissions and route them as an Ajax request.

Maybe it's a good idea to read the intro of jQuery mobile: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/intro/

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code your code only executes on the page load. If you want it to execute on an event, you need to wrap it in a function and call the function in the onclick attribute on your link.

Comment: The **A.html** should be loaded when i click the link `Go to a` in b.html, right? For example, if i click [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/) , it will be loaded and executes all stuffs which should be executed.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didnt see the script was on both pages. Are you sure you're not getting the console.log to fire twice? In Chrome's Dev tool, events that occur more then once aren't shown twice, they instead get a red counter next to the event. Are you seeing the counter number change on the page loads?